# pwquality.conf: maxsequence vs maxclassrepeat

Tags: password, security

what is please the difference between maxsequence and maxclassrepeat in /etc/security/pwquality.con?
Thank you

Comment: I can't figure out the difference between maxsequence and maxclassrepeat in the man page:https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/pwquality.conf.5.html

Answer (score 1):

1. `maxsequence` deals with allowing long sequences of consecutive numbers or letters.
   If you set `maxsequence=2`, you could include strings like "12", "89", or "bc" in your password, but not strings like "123", "890", or "bcd".
2. `maxclassrepeat` deals with allowing long sequences of the same type of character. Lowercase letters, uppercase letters, digits, and other characters are each different "classes". If you set `maxclassrepeat=3` you could use "tryThis44" in your password, because the longest string of the same class is 3 (either "try" or "his"). But "trythis44" would not be allowed, as the longest string of the same class is 7 ("trythis")